# How to get an output from a mysql insert?

Tags: mysql

Our API can concurrently get hundreds of hits at a single endpoint at any given time and each call inserts something into the database.

I need to get the last inserted ID - without using `last_inserted_id()`

Unfortunately, if we have a lot of traffic all at once, this can sometimes get a bit screwy and give the ID of something being inserted by another hit to the API.

Is there a way to add some kind of output clause that'll return the ID of what was just inserted in the same query as the insert?

Comment: Why can't you use `last_insert_id`? Do tell ...

Comment: With so much traffic coming through at once (doesn't happen all that often) we'll have multiple things being inserted at the same time. That ends up causing last_insert_id to not always match up if things get inserted at the same time through different processes.

Comment: Rubbish. `last_insert_id` is per client, it will always match that client's last insert operation. From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html), _"The value of mysql_insert_id() is affected only by statements issued within the current client connection. It is not affected by statements issued by other clients."_

Answer (score 1):

If you run INSERT with -vv, that will print the query being ran as well as the results you're looking for.

Comment: I'm doing this through PHP with PDO. Is it possible to do it somehow with that?